# R Extract character-number pairs from string/text

Tags: r

I have some data in free text. I've managed to structure it to get something like this:

**"The patient has White blood cells 10.3, hemoglobin 11.6, BNP 2,000 , lactic acid 1.5. "**

Desired output is :

**White blood cells = 10.3**

**hemoglobin = 11.6**

**lactic acid = 1.5.**

**BNP = 2,000**

Either this or a data frame with 2 columns(one for variable, another for value). Any smart way to extract such information. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have fixed positions for the values or do they vary?

Comment: vary: eg. "The patient  X  BA has White blood cells 10.3, hemoglobin 11.6, BNP 2,000 , lactic acid 1.5. " "The patient  Xsadf  has White blood cells 10.3, hemoglobin 11.63, BNP 2,000 , lactic acid 1.5. "

Comment: You don't have `BNP` in your string

Comment: @akrun Oh right, so the OP wants in differen oder?

Comment: @Julian It's related to extraction of data from free text. The problem is that the text " The patient has" is not standard. There might be another file in which this might be slightly/completely different. Basically, I need to extract 'lab test-value' pairs from free text. I should have mentioned this in question. sorry. Please suggest some other way. Order doesn't matter. Given a free text, how to extract these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `str_extract` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
number <- str_extract_all(str1, '[0-9]+.[0-9]+')[[1]]
word <- sub('The patient has', '', 
     str_extract_all(str1, perl('[^0-9.,]+ (?=[0-9])'))[[1]])
data.frame(word, number)
#                word number
#1  White blood cells    10.3
#2         hemoglobin    11.6
#3                BNP   2,000
#4        lactic acid     1.5
```

#### Update

If you have a different file with non-standard entries, it may be better to create a "key" that has all the unique words

```
key <- c('White blood cells', 'hemoglobin', 'BNP', 'lactic acid')
pat <- paste(key, collapse="|")
word <- str_extract_all(str1, pat)[[1]]
word
#[1] "White blood cells" "hemoglobin"        "BNP"              
#[4] "lactic acid"
```

The "number" is extracted as showed above.

#### Update2

I changed the regex pattern to match numbers that don't have a decimal

```
 str_extract_all(str2, '[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?')[[1]]
 #[1] "10"   "11.6" "2000" "1.5"
```

DEMO

```
[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/942qFxFmdJbkzM8a)

#### data

```
 str1 <-  "The patient has White blood cells 10.3, hemoglobin 11.6, BNP 2,000 , lactic acid 1.5. "

 str2 <-  "The patient has White blood cells 10, hemoglobin 11.6, BNP 2000 , lactic acid 1.5. "
```

Comment: I tried this. The problem is that the text " The patient has" is not standard. There might be another file in which this might be slightly/completely different. Basically, I need to extract 'lab test-value' pairs from free text. I should have mentioned this in question. sorry. Please suggest some other way.

Comment: @MohitKhare In regular expression matching, it is better to show all the patterns otherwise, it would end up something like this.  One option is to create a key of the `lab test` strings and use that as pattern to extract from the string.

Comment: Is there a way to first extract all numeric values in free text. Then divide the text into segments(using "," as delimiter).  Then, use those numbers to extract words appearing corresponding to each number in those segments.
Please suggest if this is possible.

Comment: @MohitKhare It depends upon the non-standard words.  I think the best way would be to create the key

Comment: Yes, that should work. Can you suggest how to implement that? Suppose I have list of lab tests to be used.  let's say key=c("BNP","hemoglobin")

Comment: @MohitKhare I did updated in the post about using `paste`.  The whole lab tests could be found in some database. (perhaps google might help)

Comment: For some reason, 2 digit numbers(29,85, etc) are not being captured.  What went wrong? Also, can you help my understand whats " [^0-9.,]+ (?=[0-9]) " Will help a lot in future.

Comment: @MohitKhare Could you update that new string which won't capture the digits.  I might have missed something. `[^0-9.,]+` means not including numbers 0-9 or `.` or comma. followed by a digit `(?=[0-9])`

Comment: Try with this " The individual is having White blood cells 15.3, hemoglobin 11.6, hematocrit 35.1, platelets 155,000.  Granulocytes 88.5%, lymphocytes 7.7%, glucose 180, BUN 51, creatinine 1.54, GFR 31.13, sodium 140, potassium 4.2, chloride 105, bicarbonate 29, total protein 6.2, albumin 3.8, calcium 9.3, uric acid 8.3, T-bilirubin 0.6, alkaline phosphatase 82, CPK 25, SGOT 25, SGPT 17, lactic acid 1.5. "

Comment: On a related topic @akrun, if I've set of keywords, and I want to extract content following those key words(numeric/words), how can that be done?

Comment: @MohitKhare  Could you post it as a new question with some examples and expected result

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
sapply(strsplit(gsub("^.*has ","",aa),", ")[[1]],
       function(bio){paste(gsub("[0-9.,]","",bio),gsub("[a-zA-Z]","",bio),sep="=")})
```

With your example, it gives:

```
      White blood cells 10.3              hemoglobin 11.6                   BNP 2,000             lactic acid 1.5.  
"White blood cells =   10.3"          "hemoglobin = 11.6"              "BNP  = 2,000 "      "lactic acid  =  1.5. "
```

Comment: I tried this. The problem is that the text " The patient has" is not standard. There might be another file in which this might be slightly/completely different. Basically, I need to extract 'lab test-value' pairs from free text. I should have mentioned this in question. sorry. Please suggest some other way.

Comment: @MohitKhare, is "has" before the first test-value standard ? (I'm basing my code only on the "has")

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try something like that

```
gsub("(\\s)(?=\\d)", " = ", 
      strsplit(gsub("The patient has ", "", str), ", ")[[1]],
 perl = TRUE)

## [1] "White blood cells = 10.3" "hemoglobin = 11.6" "BNP = 2,000 " "lactic acid = 1.5."
```

**Data**

```
str <- "The patient has White blood cells 10.3, hemoglobin 11.6, BNP 2,000 , lactic acid 1.5."
```

Comment: I tried this. The problem is that the text " The patient has" is not standard. There might be another file in which this might be slightly/completely different. Basically, I need to extract 'lab test-value' pairs from free text.  
I should have mentioned this in question. sorry. Please suggest some other way.